# Отладка нативного кода в андроиде

Tags: android, android-ndk

Кто нибудь пробовал сие действие? Поделитесь опытом. Я пытаюсь через cygwin + ndk-gdb. ОС - Windows.

Отладка происходит на эмуляторе.

Comment: Речь идёт о живом устройстве или об отладке в эмуляторе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отлаживать из под eclipse + gdb, то так:

1. поставить точку останова в java на место перед вызовом бинарной функции;
2. запустить код на исполнение и дождаться срабатывания точки останова;
3. перейти в папку проекта из терминала и выполнить ndk-gdb;
4. поставить точку останова на нужное место в c-коде;
5. возобновить выполнение программы в eclipse и дождаться срабатывания останова в c-коде;
6. дальше как обычно в gdb.

Это проверено на ubuntu. Под cygwin могут быть отличия.

Answer (score 0):

Я отлаживал приложения удалённо на железке, но не андроидной, а просто линуксовой. Это неплохо работает, толкьо надо иметь gdb, собранного для машины, на которой выполняется приложение (для arm в данном случае). Можно даже IDE подцепить, если она достаточно умная.

Comment: А что для отладки надо? Где почитать?

Answer (score 0):

Важны 3 вещи:

- ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 (генерирует дебажный код);
- На устройстве /data/data/<Имя пакета>/lib дожен быть gdbserver (gradle: jniDebuggable, у eclipse и ant проблем с этим нет);
- Терпение. Если что-то не работает, открываем ndk-gdb и потрошим его, указываем нужные параметры, не ссыкуем.

Comment: Этот ответ уже неактуальный, в Android Studio всё работает из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

Весь нативный код сначала отлаживаю в Visual Studio. Если нужны данные с устройства(к примеру gps), писал маленький код, передающий данные на комп. По идее, отладка с++ кода на устройстве/эмуляторе не нужна в принципе, это намного медленней и сложней.